# Agents appearing behind, instead of on top, image in main

Tags: anylogic

This is a follow-up question to modelling population density in a mock model: [Modelling population density in AnyLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225633/modelling-population-density-in-anylogic)
Now I wanted to implement those changes in my main model. The functionality works, and the agents are generated at the correct places, but somehow they appear behind the image. If I set the the image to not visible, I can see that the agents are actually generated.

Short recap of how the functionality works:
I have traced the borders of regions using a polyline on top of an image of the country. Next, I have created a function to let agents appear in a random location inside one of the polyline shapes.

I am probably overlooking something simple, but could you give me any pointers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple. Bring your agents to the front as shown in the following image:

[image: Bring to Front]

You can experiment also sending your image to back.

Comment: Agree with Felipe. All graphical shapes can be ordered this way just like in Word or ppt. You can also group objects and define orders within a group and between groups. Works well :-)

Comment: Thank you, Felipe and Benjamin :-) Overlooked that option, but it worked just fine.